# Change from capital F in \figurename

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing

To save some time when writing reports I usually define something like:

```
\newcommand{\figref}{\figurename~\ref}
```

I use the variable `\figurename` because I want to use the same code for writing in English or Swedish. But my problem here is that this gives me 'Figure' (with a capital F) in mid sentence.

So my question is if I can define a separate variable which is the same as `\figurename` but with a non-capital 'f', and how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. If I understood what you want to accomplish correct, maybe have a look at the `cleveref` package.

Comment: Quick solution: call your macro `\Figref` (with capital F) and use it at the start of a sentence and additionally define `\newcommand*{\figref}[1]{\MakeLowercase{\figurename}~\ref{#1}}` for other places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fancyref` is another language-aware package which handles this well and which has a slightly different feature set from `cleveref`. (The latter is more popular, I think, but I prefer the former.)

```
\documentclass[swedish,british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fancyref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        A figure.
        \caption{A figure caption.}\label{fig:figure}
    \end{figure}
\Fref{fig:figure} is a figure identical with \fref{fig:figure}.

\selectlanguage{swedish}
\Fref{fig:figure} \fref{fig:figure}.
\end{document}
```

[image: figures]

Answer (score 9):

I'd suggest you to use the [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package; use `\cref` for lower-case initial and `\Cref` for upper-case initial. The package is language aware:

```
\documentclass[swedish,english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}    

\begin{figure}
\caption{A test figure}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

As we see in \cref{fig:test}. \Cref{fig:test} shows...
\selectlanguage{swedish}
As we see in \cref{fig:test}. \Cref{fig:test} shows...

\end{document}
```

[image]